# Prepopulating text area in form with an attribute from a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

How can I get a text area in a Rails form to pre-populate with the attribute of a model?

For instance, with the following:

```
= form_for @posts do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :company_name
    = f.text_field :company_name
```

How could I get company_name to pre-populate with user.company_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the form_for @user so it could access the user model's attribute company_name.

```
= form_for @user do |f|
```